# shell commands invisible after ctrl+c

Tags: bash, centos, ansible

I noticed that when i run some commands in Centos , such as `ansible-doc` and `ansible-galaxy`, and  quit the output using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, all the commands typed after that are **not visible** in the bash shell.

Typing `reset` or `tset` resolves the issue, but what it the issue exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default terminal setting does local echo of each character (which allows you to edit the input line before it gets sent when you tap Enter).

Some commands control their displays in more detail: they move around the display, or accept single key-strokes, etc. These issue control commands to the terminal to disable echoing, buffering, etc.

Normally the defaults get reset by the command when it exits. But if you Ctrl-C, it does not get the chance to do that. Reset puts it back to standard settings.

Comment: thanks Paul_Pedant ! so why it works fine for other commands like more ?

Comment: More is quite cunning. Almost everything it does is added at the bottom line of the terminal. For example, h (help) racks up the displayed data as it appends the 24-line help text. I suspect it may echo your keystrokes, but it always puts something new on the bottom line. However, it does take single keystrokes, so it controls raw mode. It could set a signal trap for SIGINT, and reset the tty parameters. However, it can't trap a SIGKILL, but that still leaves the terminal in a sane state. So I don't know how it does it. top, vi, more just seem to be very careful about what they do.